# How to click button in 'alert' message on the webpage with PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, button, pyqt, pyside

On the webpage, when I create a new user, alert message displayed that 'New user was created'. And in order to continue, I have to click button 'ok'. So the thing is I don't really know how to click it.

when I need to click a regular button I do something like this:

```
doc = self.page().currentFrame().documentElement()
submit_button = doc.findFirst('input[id=my-submit-button]')
submit_button.evaluateJavaScript('this.click()')
```

But how to click button in alert message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `QWebPage::javaScriptAlert ( QWebFrame * frame, const QString & msg )` [function](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebpage.html#javaScriptAlert):

> This function is called whenever a JavaScript program running inside
>   frame calls the alert() function with the message msg.
>
> The default implementation shows the message, msg, with
>   QMessageBox::information.